# Why are my columns misaligned?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a site menu, which is listed below:

```html
<li class="dropdown dropdown-mm">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@ViewData["resProducts"]<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mm dropdown-menu-persist">
    <li class="row">
      <ul class="col-md-6">
        <li class="dropdown-header">@ViewData["resDevices"]</li>
        <li>
          <a asp-controller="Devices" asp-action="RLC21" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">
            <img src="~/img/devices/rlc-21.png" style="float: left" alt="rlc-21" />
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RL-C21</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a asp-controller="Devices" asp-action="RLR19" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">
            <img src="~/img/devices/rl-r19.png" style="float: left" alt="rlr-19" />
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RL-R19</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a asp-controller="Devices" asp-action="RLA200" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">
            <img src="~/img/devices/rl-a200.png" style="float: left" alt="rlr-19" />
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RL-A200</p>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a asp-controller="Devices" asp-action="RLA500" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">
            <img src="~/img/devices/RL_A_500_160_80.png" style="float: left" alt="rla-500" />
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RL-A500</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a asp-controller="Devices" asp-action="RLA1000" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">
            <img src="~/img/devices/RL_A_500_160_80_1.png" style="float: left" alt="rla-1000" />
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RL-A1000</p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="col-md-6">
        <li class="dropdown-header">@ViewData["resSoftware"]</li>
        <li>
          <a asp-controller="Software" asp-action="VisProbe">
            <img src="~/img/software/VIsprobeApp_64x64.ico" style="float: left" alt="rlc-21" />
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VisProbe SL</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a asp-controller="Software" asp-action="VisAnalyser">
            <img src="~/img/software/VisAnalyser_64x64.ico" style="float: left" alt="rlc-21" />
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VisAnalyser</p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

But I have strange result from this code: the first three items in the left column are shown normally, but other two are shown misaligned.

[image: See picture]

The code of menu is the same for all elements.
What may be reason for such behaviour?

Somehow misalignment depends on the size of screen. When I reduce the size of browser window misalignment changes:
[image: See next picture]

Comment: Please, also include relevant CSS. Also note that the Code Snippet feature works best for plain HTML/CSS/JS, not for server side code such as ASP.NET (Core or not). In this case it might be better to include the HTML/CSS/JS that is sent to the client, and not the server-side code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. CSS is here: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zxMElW8D_kiZnIdINnZNvZkpzGQaIoan)

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any misalignment on your first screenshot. On the second screenshot, it seems that the 3rd and the 4th images are slighly taller than the text near them, so the _floating_ images below them try to "flow around" them. If this is the case, setting `clear: left` to the `li` elements should help.

Comment: Thanks.  clear: left  helped.